# Why URI.escape fails when called on ActionView::OutputBuffer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading an application from Rails 2 to Rails 3. Apparently, calling `render()` now returns `ActionView::OutputBuffer` and not `String`. I need to pass the results of `render()` to `URI.escape()`, and this fails with exception...

#### Here is my brief testing in the console

```
ob = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new("test test")
URI.escape(ob)
    `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each_byte' for nil:NilClass`. 
        from /opt/ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:307:in `block in escape'
        from ..../ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:160:in `gsub'
        from ..../ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:160:in `gsub'
        from /opt/ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:304:in `escape'
        from /opt/ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:623:in `escape'
```

Moreover, calling to_s on OutputBuffer returns same OutputBuffer class, so I cannot even convert this buffer into a honest string?

```
ob.to_s.class 
    ActionView::OutputBuffer
```

Of course, calling URI.escape("test test") returns "test%20test" as expected, so this is not URI problem.

Environment:

- ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]
- Rails 3.2.1

My question is: **Why does this happen and how can I work around this issue?**

**Update:** Apparently, using `'' + ob` as a form of `ob.to_s` converts OutputBuffer to String, which effectively works around the problem... But my question '*why does this happen*' still remains, e.g. is this a bug, should I report it, or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a [bug in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3496):

> When calling gsub with a block on an ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer the global variables $1, $2, etc. for referencing submatches are not always properly set (anymore?) when the block is called.

This is why URI.escape (and any other function that uses `gsub()` will fail on ActiveSupprt::Safebuffer.

There are [several](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1555) [discussions](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/937b63facc991f96) about this, apparently the safest route right now is to call to_str before passing SafeBuffer to anything that can call gsub, e.g. `URI.encode`, `escape_javascript` and similar functions.

My other quesion about `to_s` returning the same class - obviously safe buffer will return itself and not a bare String, this is by design. In order to get a true String, `.to_str` can be used.

Comment: I was sending a `render_to_string()` result as a POST value with RestClient, and this was driving me mad. You'd think a method named `render_to_string` would return a String :) So, thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that Rails 3 introduced the concept of [safe buffers](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)

In Rails3 your Views are protected by XSS by default by making all rendering be safely escaped unless you explicitly use the `raw()` helper or `html_safe`

Comment: OK, this explains why to_s returns same class. However, I don't think `URI.escape(ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("test test"))` should be throwing an exception, so I'm inclined to believe now this is some kind of  a bug in Rails or URI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb bug that i'm currently encountering in Rails 5.  My stupid workaround was to do something like

```
ob = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new("test test")
URI.escape(ob.to_sym.to_s)
```

Again it works, but i'm still looking for a cleaner solution.