# How to render rails mailer views in Mailgun HTTP API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mailgun

I'm using Mailgun HTTP API to send emails from rails application.But I'm not able to render the mailer views. This is my mailer class.

```
class MailgunMails < ActionMailer::Base

    def send_complex_message
      data = Multimap.new
      data[:from] = "Excited User <postmasters@#{@@domain}>"
      data[:to] = "alice@example.com"
      data[:subject] = "Hello"
      data[:html] = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/views/mailgun_mails/send_complex_message.html.erb", 'r').to_s.html_safe  
      ## also tried
      data[:html] = render(template: "send_complex_message.html.erb")
      response = RestClient.post "https://api:#{@@private_key}"\
      "@api.mailgun.net/v2/#{@@domain}/messages", data

      response = JSON.parse(response)

    end

end
```

But that throws:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass

How do I use mailer views with Mailgun API.

PS: I know there are many gems available to use mailgun with rails but none of them gives full functionality as the API does.

**IF there is any alternative way to send emails from the api using the rails views,  I'm waiting for that answer. I just don't know how to do that (even if it doesn't use actionmailer)**

**FULL error trace**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:307:in `block in escape'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:177:in `gsub'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:177:in `gsub'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:304:in `escape'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:623:in `escape'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:150:in `handle_key'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:143:in `block in build_stream'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:142:in `collect'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:142:in `build_stream'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:53:in `initialize'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:18:in `new'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/payload.rb:18:in `generate'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `new'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
... 2 levels...
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1281843520849433682__process_action__callbacks'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:503:in `process'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `new'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/actionmailer-4.0.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/example/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Comment: So, you are sending an email in your Mailer by calling their API inside of it? It's a pattern that I haven't seen before. http://www.leemunroe.com/send-automated-email-ruby-rails-mailgun/

Comment: Apparently yes. I can't use the smtp settings. ( I don't want to use) as my sending email will be changed dynamically. What is the right way to do what I want to achieve?

Comment: Why can't you use SMTP? Just curious. You can dynamically change the email templates and still use the default ActionMailer behavior. You can change the views using render method.

Comment: I can't change the sender email address dynamically in SMTP. Also there are other features in API I want to use.

Comment: Sounds good. So, can you copy and paste the entire error message?

Comment: added the full error message.

Comment: Interesting... It looks like there is a bug in Ruby code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469825/why-uri-escape-fails-when-called-on-actionviewoutputbuffer

Comment: Well I did come to that post before asking this, but I didn't get what to do. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using the render_to_string method? I believe you want to dynamically generate the view content. Reading up the view template by opening up the file would not run any Ruby code in it.

```
    class MailgunMails < ActionMailer::Base

        def send_complex_message
          data = Multimap.new
          data[:from] = "Excited User <postmasters@#{@@domain}>"
          data[:to] = "alice@example.com"
          data[:subject] = "Hello"
          html_output = render_to_string template: "mailgun_mails/send_complex_message"
          data[:html] = html_output.to_str
          response = RestClient.post "https://api:#{@@private_key}"\
          "@api.mailgun.net/v2/#{@@domain}/messages", data

          response = JSON.parse(response)

        end

     end
```

Comment: Try to use "to_str" method, as shown above in the updated code. to_str to force it to return true strings.

Comment: That works but only as a pure string. The HTML is not rendered. (the links etc)

Comment: I tried `html_safe` but it gives the same error message

Comment: That should work, you need to see what your code is doing in the view template. Are you missing the "=" in your link_to? <%= link_to ...%>?

Comment: user2675010 is correct. The template is pulled and passed to the message body but the string is not rendered, instead the raw string is passed.

Comment: Make sure your HTML template is clean HTML and starts with <!DOCTYPE> with no extras. Test it with some simple basic HTML markup.