# Mailgun will not recognize Rails view templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailgun

In my action mailer, I'm not sure how I am supposed to render my `views/app_mailer/sample_email.html.erb` template within the body of the email...

```
class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV["api_key"]
    message_params = {:from    => ENV["username"],
                      :to      => @user.email,
                      :subject => "Welcome, #{@user.name}!",
                      :html => "<%= render 'sample_email' %>"}
    mg_client.send_message ENV["domain"], message_params
  end

end
```

I looked through [How to render rails mailer views in Mailgun HTTP API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516255/how-to-render-rails-mailer-views-in-mailgun-http-api) , but I couldn't get it to work.  I'm using the `mailgun-ruby` gem (& the `premailer-rails` gem, but that might not apply to this question).

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `:html => render_to_string(template: "sample_email")` as suggested in the related question you found?

Comment: I actually got it to work with `:html => (render_to_string(template: "../views/app_mailer/sample_email")).to_str`  Thanks for jogging my thinking on this!  It looks like I had to give it an explicit file path and to use the `.to_str` method to prevent the `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each_byte' for nil:NilClass` error